# SailJs stack a middelware in controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

I'm new to Sails JS, and currently, I am trying to stack a middleware in my controller. Here is my code:

```
module.exports = {
  yow: function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('a')

    next()
  }, function(req, res) {
    Product.query('SELECT * FROM product', function(err, result) {
      res.setLocale('in');

      res.render('yow', {
        product: result
      })
    })
  },
};
```

The `console.log('a')` runs normally. I can see ***a*** is printed in my terminal. But the page shows a 404 page, which means the second function is not being read.

Can somebody light me up?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please show your routing

Comment: Errrm, I'm kinda new to this, by 'routing' you mean the `config/routes.js` ?

Comment: yes please      config/routes.js

Comment: `next()` callback is causing the error

Comment: `module.exports.routes = {
  '/': {
    view: 'homepage'
  },
  '/yow': 'productController.yow'
};`

Comment: @Gaurav above controller is productController.js

Comment: @p0k8_ why do you say so ?,

Comment: Please go through this 

http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/middleware

Comment: and what kind of exporting is this